# Jenkins sh returnstdout returns empty but prints

Tags: jenkins, tcsh

In my pipeline Im trying to compare the results of 2 sh commands:
To run the sh command I added:

```
def some_var = "empty2"
some_var = sh(returnStdout: true, returnStatus :false, script: """some command""").trim()
```

In my pipeline log I see the output as expected from the command (long 100s of lines).
However when printing the value of some_var  it is always empty.

I tried replacing the sh command with an echo, and that seemed to work as expected (variable got the value of the command).

How is it possible that I can see the output in my pipeline, but it is not assigned to my variable.

edit:

I checked the output is about 512 lines, 23190 chars the limit of groovy should be 65535 characters. note im also not getting any assignment errors.

The step is green, indicating there is no fail/error ?

The shell jenkins is using is /bin/tcsh

Comment: Could it be that your script only writes to `stderr`? [sh step reference](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script) explicitly says that standard error will still be printed to the build log.

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev In that case the step would fail and turn red right? the step is green.

Comment: Well, that's not necessary true. Jenkins only checks the return code, it doesn't test if stderr is not empty.

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev Thanks that fixed it, I thought jenkins would fail if it had stderr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash like shells you can add `2>&1` to your command to redirect stderr to stdout.

In csh like shells (including tcsh) adding `>& /dev/stdout` should work if you have `/dev/stdout` defined. If not - you can try `|& cat`

Comment: you pointed me in the right direction,  >& /dev/stdout did the trick instead of 2>&1. I did not mention that I was using tcsh before, I added it now to make it more clear. If you can add it to your answer I will accept it.

Comment: Right. Added tcsh specific answer.